# rsync: connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have a error in rsync after update to use `iconv` option. I search in everything but not find any solution

The command is:

```
rsync -rltPDvhbz -e 'ssh -vvvv' --progress --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8 --exclude={'.Spotlight*', '.TemporaryItems', '.Trashes'} --delete --backup-dir=/Volumes/wd/meumundo/backup/  user@192.168.0.7:/mnt/nas/ /Volumes/wd/meumundo/original/
```

I run in Mac with the origin is in raspberry `raspberrypi 5.15.32-v8+` and destination is on external disc with exfat.

I try to update to same version in MAC and in raspberry but the mac version by brew is most updated:

- Mac:

```
rsync  version 3.2.4  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2022 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: https://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, symlinks, symtimes, hardlinks, hardlink-specials,
    hardlink-symlinks, IPv6, atimes, batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs,
    xattrs, optional protect-args, iconv, no prealloc, stop-at, crtimes,
    file-flags
Optimizations:
    no SIMD-roll, no asm-roll, openssl-crypto, no asm-MD5
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

- raspberry:

```
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2020 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: https://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, hardlink-specials, symlinks, IPv6, atimes,
    batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs, xattrs, optional protect-args, iconv,
    symtimes, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    no SIMD, no asm, openssl-crypto
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

Using the verbose ssh I get logs:

```
debug2: channel 0: window 1990734 sent adjust 98226
debug2: channel 0: window 1990690 sent adjust 90078
debug2: channel 0: window 1982477 sent adjust 106483
debug2: channel 0: window 1990690 sent adjust 90078
debug2: channel 0: window 1982522 sent adjust 106438
debug2: channel 0: window 1997357 sent adjust 99795
debug2: channel 0: window 1997790 sent adjust 96134
debug2: channel 0: window 1990419 sent adjust 101054
debug2: channel 0: window 1991175 sent adjust 100128
debug2: channel 0: window 1992523 sent adjust 96437
debug2: channel 0: write failed
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: send eow
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (7994120 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [generator=3.2.4]
```

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks